# Links are not clickable under an iframe in chrome or firefox

Tags: html, iframe

I have created an iframe to hold navigation for my website. The navigation has dropdown elements. Works great - however, the links on the page that are under the iframe area no longer work properly. I have tried using the z-index, but it only allows one of the div area's links to function at a time. I need to be able to use both the links in the iframe, and the links on the page at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Those elements are being properly kept within their frame.

I would strongly recommend against using `<iframe>` for navigation in this manner, for several reasons:

- Search engines don't link to your frameset, they link to your inner page, generally
- Placement problems, like the one you are having
- Screen reader confusion, and other accessibility issues

Comment: There are many, many pages in this site and I do not want to have to update all of them every time there is a change in navigation. So, what I need to be able to do is click on a link in the dropdown or click on a link on the page. Both need to be functional. Works in Explorer, but not in Chrome or Firefox. Is there a way to click on links without z-indexing one over the other?

Comment: Use some form of server-side include so you don't have to do this every time.  Since your navigation is already split out, a find-and-replace in files should be trivial.  I don't think you are going to find a consistent solution with iframes.

Comment: Try using some form of server-side templating, such as [mustache](http://mustache.github.io/), which allows you to make partial templates and include them in other templates. You could also do this on the client-side using javascript and a similar templating library ([mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js), [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/), [dust.js](http://akdubya.github.io/dustjs/), etc...)